# Issue with NordVPN app installation in Linux Tails (Terminal)

Tags: software-installation, vpn, tails-os

I need to install [NordVPN](https://www.nordvpn.com) into Linux [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/). Followed the instructions to perform in a Terminal window for the normal NordVPN [https://nordvpn.com/download/linux/](https://www.nordvpn.com) :

```
sudo apt-get install /home/amnesia/Desktop/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
```

After a few seconds, confirmed I wished to proceed, then got:

```
*Get:1 /home/amnesia/Desktop/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb nordvpn-release all 1.0.0 [5,358 B]  
[INFO] Saving package changes  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 194, in __getitem__
    return self._weakref[key]  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__  
    o = self.data[key]()  
KeyError: 'nordvpn-release'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 198, in __getitem__  
    rawpkg = self._cache[key]
KeyError: 'nordvpn-release'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/local/sbin/tails-additional-software", line 671, in <module>  
    apt_hook_pre()  
  File "/usr/local/sbin/tails-additional-software", line 459, in apt_hook_pre  
    if not apt_cache[package_name].is_installed:  
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 200, in __getitem__  
    raise KeyError('The cache has no package named %r' % key)  
KeyError: "The cache has no package named 'nordvpn-release'"  
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file  
 '/home/amnesia/Desktop/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)  
E: Sub-process /usr/local/sbin/tails-additional-software apt-pre returned an error code (1)  
E: Failure running script /usr/local/sbin/tails-additional-software apt-pre*
```

How do I overcome this failure?

Comment: As you're new here: If one of the answers below solved your problem, don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of its text, which means Yes, this answer is the most useful of all!  https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2):

Since [Linux Tails](https://tails.boum.org) forces all connections through [Tor](https://www.torproject.org), it won't work. However, [this blog post](https://thetinhat.com/tutorials/darknets/tor-vpn-using-both.html) says you can use a VPN with [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) (less safe, they say) or [Whonix](https://www.whonix.org/)  (more safe, they say).

Therefore, I suggest you review the pros and cons of Tor Browser on another Linux vs Whonix, and decide which suits your needs better.